# using IF loop to grep for a pattern and execute statements

Tags: bash, awk

I am having a directory in which it contains 20 sub-directories and all sub-directories names end with "**_b**". In each sub-directory same file name "**error.txt**" is there. I need to loop-in to all the sub-directories and grep for a word called "**ECHO**" in the **"sub-directory/error.txt**" file and if the word is present I need to execute statement one, if the word "**ECHO**" is not present in file "**sub-directory/error.txt**" I need to execute statement two.
I tried like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
File="./error.txt"
for d in *_b;
do
if grep -q "ECHO" "$File"; then
echo "$d:";
    Statement 1 
echo "------------------";
else 
echo "$d:";
    Statement 2 
echo "------------------";
fi
done
```

But I am not getting the desired output , I am getting output as :

```
grep: ./error.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: *find \*_b -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname error.txt -print0 | while read -r -d '' file; do if grep -qi ECHO "$file"; then ... else ... fi; done* is the better choice loop over non-trivial file names (example) and maybe case-insensitive search (i) give more results

Comment: Not the problem you're asking about but don't duplicate code - move the `echo "$d:";` to before your `if-else` and the `echo "------------------";` to after it. You don't need the `;`s btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just adjusting the path should work

```
#!/bin/bash
File="error.txt"
for d in *_b;
do
if grep -q "ECHO" $d/"$File"; then
echo "$d:";
    Statement 1
echo "------------------";
else
echo "$d:";
    Statement 2
echo "------------------";
fi
done
```

Comment: I am still seeing the same error as: **grep: error.txt: No such file or directory**. Here error.txt is a common file name in all 20 sub-directories, I need to loop in to all 20 sub-directories and grep for the word **"ECHO"** in **"error.txt"** file.

Comment: sure it isn't **grep: \*_b/error.txt: No such file or directory** i can barely see a reason how `$d` can be empty (nevertheless path should quoted with double quotes)